# Blazor WASM (not asp.net core hosted) api calls?

Tags: c#, api, blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

Can you make API calls to other domains when publishing a non asp.net core hosted blazor web assembly application?

Or do you need to choose asp.net core hosted.

Comment: sure, the service on the other domain just has to allow your requests via CORS policy.

Answer (score 3):

> Can you make API calls to other domains

Yes, you can make calls to any URL. But those APIs have to allow it, make sure you know about CORS.